# RabbitMQ: identify messages from same prefetch

Tags: rabbitmq, prefetch

My producer looks like this:

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
        $settings['amqp']['host'],
        $settings['amqp']['port'],
        $settings['amqp']['username'],
        $settings['amqp']['password']
);

$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare($settings['amqp']['queue'], false, true, false, false);

$msg = array();
$msg['time'] = time();

$msg = new AMQPMessage(json_encode($msg), array('delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT));
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', $settings['amqp']['queue']);

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

And my consumer looks like this:

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
        $settings['amqp']['host'],
        $settings['amqp']['port'],
        $settings['amqp']['username'],
        $settings['amqp']['password']
);

$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare($settings['amqp']['queue'], false, true, false, false);

$callback = function($message) {
        //echo $message->body . "\n";
        //echo $message->delivery_info['delivery_tag'] . "\n";
        var_dump($message) . "\n";
        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
};

$channel->basic_qos(null, 30, null);
$channel->basic_consume($settings['amqp']['queue'], '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

try {
        while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
                $channel->wait();
        }
} catch (Exception $e){
        die();
}
```

Since I'm setted *basic_qos* to *null, 30, null* my consumers retrieve blocks of 30 messages from the cluster.

My goal is identify these 30 as a group. And the next 30 as a diferent group.

Something like that:

**ATTENTION: Example PHP + BASH !!!**

```
$callback = function($message) {
        mkdir -p /tmp/$message->delivery_info['prefetch_group']
        echo $message->body > /tmp/$message->delivery_info['prefetch_group']/$message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']
};
```

At the end. I will have one dir for each block with the content of the messages.

Of course *$message->delivery_info['prefetch_group']* doesn't exist. And I didn't found anything usefull into *$message*

**It would be ideal send the basis_ack for each block (30 messages) only if all the process is done.**

Any idea to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from processing 30 messages before receiving another 30 messages.

- Wait to send the acknowledgement until after you have processed the 30th message
- Be sure to set the `multiple` flag to "true"; this will acknowledge all messages received up to the 30th message
- Obviously you'll need to keep the messages in the order they were received (they come one at a time from the broker). This can be done by sorting on [DeliveryTag](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.delivery-tag).

As a caveat, if for example the message processor fails/crashes with the 30th message, and you don't acknowledge the other 29, then you're going to end up getting those re-delivered to you, so this may be something to consider in your design.

Also note [from the spec](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.qos.prefetch-count):

> The server may send less data in advance than allowed by the client's specified prefetch windows but it MUST NOT send more.

Comment: You proposal doesn't work with my example (basic_consume). To do those, I need to use basic_get rigth?. As in my answer.

Comment: Prefetch count only applies with `basic.consume`, which is asynchronous. A `basic.get` is a synchronous function returning at most one message, and there is no such thing as a pre-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I have done this.

Using *basic_get* instead *basic_consume* like that:

**CODE NOT PROBED !!!. Writed like an example.**

```
 16 $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
 17         $settings['amqp']['host'],
 18         $settings['amqp']['port'],
 19         $settings['amqp']['username'],
 20         $settings['amqp']['password']
 21 );
 22
 23 $channel = $connection->channel();
 24 $channel->queue_declare($settings['amqp']['queue'], false, true, false, false);
 25
 26 $messages = Array();
 27 for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) {
 28         $messages[] = $channel->basic_get($settings['amqp']['queue']);
 29 }
 30
 31 $now = time();
 32 foreach($messages as $message) {
 33         // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH EACH MSG
 34         // system('mkdir -p /tmp/' . $now);
            // system('echo ' . $message->body . '> /tmp/' . $now . '/' . $message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
 35         echo $message->body . "\n";
 36 }
 37 
 38 // system('tar /tmp/' . $now . '.gz cvfz /tmp/' . $now);
 39
 40 foreach($messages as $message) {
 41         $channel->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);    
 42 }
 43
 44 $channel->close();
 45 $connection->close();
```

This in only a POC. Would be necessary:

- Be sure there is a message before push to $messages (Line 28)
- Control many possible errors.
- Daemonize the consumer in some way.

I need read more about *basic_get* vs *basic_consume* but this solutions seems good to me.